# How do you solve error on node install i can't run any node commands

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I am trying to run commands like `npm install` and cannot I keep getting this on my terminal

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\RUSSELL\React\els-client-main/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\RUSSELL\React\els-client-main\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RUSSELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-05T17_29_16_857Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm using node version 16 and npm version 8

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that npm can't find the `package.json` file. When you run the `npm install` command, keep a few things in mind.

1. You've already run the `npm init` command to initialise your directory and add a `package.json` file.

   ```
   $ npm init
   ```

   You can also run `npm init -y` to skip the configuration (say yes to everything).

   ```
   $ npm init -y
   ```

   Make sure to run this command in your project directory!
2. If the `package.json` file has already been set up, make sure that you are in the correct directory! If you want to navigate through directories in the terminal, keep the following commands in mind.

   | Command | Description |
   | --- | --- |
   | `cd ..` | Move back a directory |
   | `cd folder` | Move into a directory |
   | `ls` | (Linux and PowerShell) See the files and folders in a directory |
   | `dir` | (CMD and PowerShell) See the files and folders in a directory |
3. Only when you're in the correct directory should you run `npm install`. Then, it should find `package.json` and install the dependencies.

   ```
   $ npm install
   ```

<sub>Don't type the dollar signs (*$*) in the terminal examples!</sub>